# Redirecting from command line to a D program

Tags: terminal, pipe, d, io-redirection

I want to redirect a .txt file from the command line into an exetuable written in D.

```
$ ./myprogram < data.txt
```

This text file consist of numbers that I want to print to the screen. So far, my program consists of this:

```
import std.stdio, std.file;

void main(string[] args) {

    string file = args[2];
    writeln(read(file));
}
```

But this is not correct; could someone explain me how redirects work and how I transfer the data in to my D program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **stdin** to read input like that:

```
import std.stdio, std.file;

void main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (line; stdin.byLine())
    {
        writeln(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What you currently have tries to get the input file as an argument but your program never sees that because, when you do input redirection:

1. The shell attaches that file to your input stream `stdio`; and
2. The redirection bit is removed entirely from the command line before you get it.

In other words, when you do input redirection like that, the data shows up on the standard input stream and not via an argument.

Hence you will need to use `readln` or similar to get the data.

A classic way for UNIXy programs to handle this is to check their arguments. If one exists, it opens the file and processes that. If an argument is *not* given, it simply uses standard input.

That allows you to run your command in many different ways:

```
testprog                           # uses standard input (terminal).
testprog <myfile                   # uses standard input but from file.
testprog myfile                    # opens file and uses it.
```